# autocomplete is missing css styles

Tags: autocomplete, typeahead.js

not sure why, but my typeahead.js remote autocomplete stopped working. I have not changed any codes regarding typeahead.js, but since it is broken, I must be wrong. Can you please take a look at my [site here](http://www.digrin.com/)? I would create jsfiddle, but thanks to `Cross-Origin Request Blocked` I was not able to include my dependences.
**Problem**:
If I type "JN" or "AAP" this is what I get (suggestions are in plain text):
[image: typeahead.js autocomplete without css]
Also I would like to know why autocomplete starts after third character input, not first (I use `minLength: 1`).
I'll paste most of my code here, since I will probably change my site in future.
**Imports**:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/typeahead.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.bundle.js"></script>
```

**Javascrip**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            var stocks = new Bloodhound({
                datumTokenizer: function (datum) {
                    return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(datum.tokens);
                },
                queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
                limit: 5,
                remote: {
                    url: "/search/autocomplete/",
                    replace: function(url, query) {
                        return url + "?q=" + query;
                    },
                    filter: function(stocks) {
                        return $.map(stocks, function(data) {
                            return {
                                tokens: data.tokens,
                                symbol: data.symbol,
                                name: data.name
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
            stocks.initialize();
            $('.typeahead').typeahead(null, {
                    name: 'stocks',
                    displayKey: 'name',
                    minLength: 1, // send AJAX request only after user type in at least X characters
                    source: stocks.ttAdapter(),
                    templates: {
                        suggestion: function(data){
                          return '<p>' + data.name + ' (<strong>' + data.symbol + '</strong>)</p>';
                        }
                    }
            }).on('typeahead:selected', function (obj, stock) {
                window.location.href = "/stocks/detail/" + stock.symbol;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

**form**:

```
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12 col-lg-3 navbar-right">
            <form method="get" action="/search/" role="search">
                <div class="input-group input-sm">
                <input type="text" class="form-control typeahead"
                       placeholder="Stock symbol" autocomplete="off" id="id_q" name="q">
                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

And this is my typeahead.css:

```
/*
 * typehead.js-bootstrap3.less
 * @version 0.2.3
 * https://github.com/hyspace/typeahead.js-bootstrap3.less
 *
 * Licensed under the MIT license:
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/MIT
 */
.has-warning .twitter-typeahead .tt-input,
.has-warning .twitter-typeahead .tt-hint {
  border-color: #8a6d3b;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
}
.has-warning .twitter-typeahead .tt-input:focus,
.has-warning .twitter-typeahead .tt-hint:focus {
  border-color: #66512c;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 6px #c0a16b;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 6px #c0a16b;
}
.has-error .twitter-typeahead .tt-input,
.has-error .twitter-typeahead .tt-hint {
  border-color: #a94442;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
}
.has-error .twitter-typeahead .tt-input:focus,
.has-error .twitter-typeahead .tt-hint:focus {
  border-color: #843534;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 6px #ce8483;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 6px #ce8483;
}
.has-success .twitter-typeahead .tt-input,
.has-success .twitter-typeahead .tt-hint {
  border-color: #3c763d;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
}
.has-success .twitter-typeahead .tt-input:focus,
.has-success .twitter-typeahead .tt-hint:focus {
  border-color: #2b542c;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 6px #67b168;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 6px #67b168;
}
.input-group .twitter-typeahead:first-child .tt-input,
.input-group .twitter-typeahead:first-child .tt-hint {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
}
.input-group .twitter-typeahead:last-child .tt-input,
.input-group .twitter-typeahead:last-child .tt-hint {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
}
.input-group.input-group-sm .twitter-typeahead .tt-input,
.input-group.input-group-sm .twitter-typeahead .tt-hint {
  height: 30px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
select.input-group.input-group-sm .twitter-typeahead .tt-input,
select.input-group.input-group-sm .twitter-typeahead .tt-hint {
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
}
textarea.input-group.input-group-sm .twitter-typeahead .tt-input,
textarea.input-group.input-group-sm .twitter-typeahead .tt-hint,
select[multiple].input-group.input-group-sm .twitter-typeahead .tt-input,
select[multiple].input-group.input-group-sm .twitter-typeahead .tt-hint {
  height: auto;
}
.input-group.input-group-sm .twitter-typeahead:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) .tt-input,
.input-group.input-group-sm .twitter-typeahead:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) .tt-hint {
  border-radius: 0;
}
.input-group.input-group-sm .twitter-typeahead:first-child .tt-input,
.input-group.input-group-sm .twitter-typeahead:first-child .tt-hint {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}
.input-group.input-group-sm .twitter-typeahead:last-child .tt-input,
.input-group.input-group-sm .twitter-typeahead:last-child .tt-hint {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
}
.input-group.input-group-lg .twitter-typeahead .tt-input,
.input-group.input-group-lg .twitter-typeahead .tt-hint {
  height: 46px;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.33;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
select.input-group.input-group-lg .twitter-typeahead .tt-input,
select.input-group.input-group-lg .twitter-typeahead .tt-hint {
  height: 46px;
  line-height: 46px;
}
textarea.input-group.input-group-lg .twitter-typeahead .tt-input,
textarea.input-group.input-group-lg .twitter-typeahead .tt-hint,
select[multiple].input-group.input-group-lg .twitter-typeahead .tt-input,
select[multiple].input-group.input-group-lg .twitter-typeahead .tt-hint {
  height: auto;
}
.input-group.input-group-lg .twitter-typeahead:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) .tt-input,
.input-group.input-group-lg .twitter-typeahead:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) .tt-hint {
  border-radius: 0;
}
.input-group.input-group-lg .twitter-typeahead:first-child .tt-input,
.input-group.input-group-lg .twitter-typeahead:first-child .tt-hint {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
  border-top-left-radius: 6px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}
.input-group.input-group-lg .twitter-typeahead:last-child .tt-input,
.input-group.input-group-lg .twitter-typeahead:last-child .tt-hint {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
  border-top-right-radius: 6px;
}
.twitter-typeahead {
  width: 100%;
}
.input-group .twitter-typeahead {
  display: table-cell !important;
  float: left;
}
.twitter-typeahead .tt-hint {
  color: #999999;
}
.twitter-typeahead .tt-input {
  z-index: 2;
}
.twitter-typeahead .tt-input[disabled],
.twitter-typeahead .tt-input[readonly],
fieldset[disabled] .twitter-typeahead .tt-input {
  cursor: not-allowed;
  background-color: #eeeeee !important;
}
.tt-dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  min-width: 160px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin: 2px 0 0;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
  box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
  background-clip: padding-box;
  *border-right-width: 2px;
  *border-bottom-width: 2px;
}
.tt-dropdown-menu .tt-suggestion {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  clear: both;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #333333;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.tt-dropdown-menu .tt-suggestion.tt-cursor {
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: 0;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  color: #262626;
}
.tt-dropdown-menu .tt-suggestion.tt-cursor a {
  color: #262626;
}
.tt-dropdown-menu .tt-suggestion p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I used newer version of bootstrap.min.js or typeahead.js and my typeahead.css stopped working. Using [new css file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyspace/typeahead.js-bootstrap3.less/master/typeahead.css) fixed my problem.
Hm, its weird it says it it same version, but there are 4 removals and 18 additions.